# jQuery Validation - error messages value

Tags: jquery, validation, unobtrusive-validation, jquery-validate

I have a jquery validation rule

```
$.validator.addMethod("hexcolor", function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^(#){1}([a-fA-F0-9]){6}$/.test(value);
}, "Please insert a valid hex color (#______)");

$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("hexcolor", function (options) {
    options.rules['hexcolor'] = options.params;
    options.messages['hexcolor'] = options.message;
});
```

On Html, i bind the validation like this

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.Color, new { data_val = "true", data_val_hexcolor = "Html Error message" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(p => p.Color)
```

When the input is invalid, i always get "Html Error message" as error message, instead of plugin's one "Please insert a valid hex color (#______)"

[image: Jquery validation]

How can i get the plugin's error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure what you're trying to do here, but you explicitly set the validation message to the value of the data_val_hexcolor here:

```
options.messages['hexcolor'] = options.message;
```

The message property of options sent to an adapter contains the value of the data_val_[rulename] attribute.

That's normally what you'd want in ASP.NET MVC, because that allows you to set the validation message from the server, like you do here, rather than in Javascript:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor( ... data_val_hexcolor = "Html Error message" })
```

You can ignore the message sent from the server by removing the assignment to `options.messages['hexcolor']` entirely, or you could replace that line by:

```
// Only add view defined message if not empty:
if (options.message)
{
   options.messages['hex_color'] = options.message;
}
```

... and then set data_val_hexcolor to an empty string in your view (you can't remove the attribute, obviously, because it's the existance of the attribute that triggers the validation rule):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor( ... data_val_hexcolor = "" })
```

Comment: Exacly what i needed to know. Thank you